# Redirect to notification setting directly from iOS app that having support of iOS8+

Tags: ios, notifications, settings, uialertview, uialertcontroller

My requirement is that - if notification for the app is turned off by user and user opens the app at that time it will give alert for turn on notification for the app and when click on okay button of alert view  app will redirect to notification screen where user need to click on switch button only to turn on the notifications.

Is it possible in ios8+ ?

I want to redirect this screen

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This code will redirect you to setting of notifications.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone)
{
    NSLog(@" Push Notification ON");
}
else
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Push Notification Service Disable ,please enable it."  message:nil  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
    {
           @try
           {
                NSLog(@"tapped ok");
                BOOL canOpenSettings = (UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
                if (canOpenSettings)
                {
                     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                }
           }
           @catch (NSException *exception)
          {

          }
    }]];
   [self.view presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

It will redirect to following screen

[image]

Comment: Thanks sara,Is it possible redirect screen that i added in my question ?

Comment: It is not possible well I m not sure about this.